# Fullcalendar io takes time to generate calendar only in IE

Tags: fullcalendar

Here is the ajax code, am doubting the resource section because it has 645 data's in the array. when i put small amount of static data's it works. Chrome, firefox and safari works fin only in IE it takes time to generate the calendar.
any one can help me on this please.

```
//get vehicle to calendar
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("WP", "WeeklyPlan")',
        cache: false,
        data: {

        }, success: function (data) {
            resource = []
            events = []
            var vehiclesWithReserations = data.vehicles;

            if (vehiclesWithReserations == null) {
                hideLoader();
                toastr.warning(data.message);
                return;
            } else if (vehiclesWithReserations.length == 0) {
                hideLoader();
            }

            var holidayList = data.holidays;

            $.each(vehiclesWithReserations, function (i, v) {

                resource.push({
                    id: v.FuhrparkFahrzeugID,
                    title: v.ModellName,
                    field: v.LocationId,
                    zuteilung: v.ZutName,
                    nvx: v.NVX
                });

                for (var q = 0; q < v.Reservations.length; q++) {
                    events.push({
                        id: v.Reservations[q].ReservationID,
                        resourceId: v.FuhrparkFahrzeugID,
                        start: moment(v.Reservations[q].DateFrom).toDate(),
                        end: moment(v.Reservations[q].DateTo).toDate()
                    })
                }
            });
            generatecalender(holidayList);
        }
```

Comment: use the developer tools in IE vs other browsers to find what is slowing things down, they have performance related tools and debuggers. We can't really tell you directly. Although, IE is, in general, slower when executing JS than the latest versions of other browsers, and doesn't deal well with larger datasets. 600 Resources does sound like a lot, plus you are building them manually in a loop - why not get your server to do that work?

Comment: we are getting the data's from the server and just pushing it to the array and calling the resource and events variable in the full calendar initialization.

Comment: Yes I can see that. What I asked was: why can't the server output the data in the correct format to begin with, and save you all that JavaScript processing? If you want to improve the performance of the script in your page, a very simple way to do that is to reduce the amount of script. Transforming data from what format to another, which is what you seem to be doing in that code, is a great example of something the server would do much faster.

Comment: since am a front-end developer am not aware of this.. if you don't mind can you update the code here please

Comment: I can't see what your server code is doing right now, so it's not possible to post an alternative version of it. But quite simply the goal should be for the server to output JSON which is already in the format required by the `events` and `resources` options in fullCalendar - instead of you having to loop through the data in JS and transpose the field names.

Comment: You would be aiming to eliminate the whole of the `$.each(vehiclesWithReserations, function (i, v) {` loop, so you can just push some properties e.g. `data.events` and `data.resources` directly into fullCalendar, without any extra processing in the browser side.

Comment: ok cool i will look into it. Thanks a lot for the help and the feedback.

Comment: No worries. I'm not saying that will solve all your issues but it will certainly reduce the amount of unnecessary JS processing on your page.